Build Fails on Azure Pipelines with Deprecated char_traits Warnings in React Native iOS App
I am trying to build a React Native iOS app using Azure Pipelines, but the build fails due to warnings related to deprecated char_traits in the RCT-Folly library. Here are the relevant parts of the error logs and my setup:
Error Log
⚠️ /Users/runner/work/1/s/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/RCT-Folly/folly/Range.h:176:16: 'char_traits' is deprecated: char_traits for T not equal to char, wchar_t, char8_t, char16_t, or char32_t is non-standard and is provided for a temporary period. It will be removed in LLVM 18, so please migrate off of it. [-Wdeprecated-declarations] typedef std::char_traits<typename std::remove_const<value_type>::type>
BUILD FAILED
The following build commands failed:
CompileC /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/raurauAdmin-gztdyzcynucaikdocaqdcfvsvqqd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/RCT-Folly.build/Objects-normal/arm64/json.o /Users/runner/work/1/s/ios/Pods/RCT-Folly/folly/json.cpp normal arm64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'RCT-Folly' from project 'Pods')
Podfile is below
Podfile and CI yaml Configuration
Here is the relevant section of my Podfile and my CI yaml:
platform :ios, '12.0'
pod 'Firebase', :modular_headers => true
# other pods...

post_install do |installer|
  installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
    project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['GCC_WARN_ABOUT_DEPRECATED_FUNCTIONS'] = 'NO'
      end
    end
  end
end

**CI YAML Pipeline Configuration**

trigger:
- main  # Trigger the pipeline on changes to the main branch

variables:
  - group: 'New variable group 12-Sep'  # Link to variable group for shared variables
  - name: System.Debug
    value: true  # Enable debug logging for detailed output

jobs:
- job: Build_iOS
  displayName: Build iOS App
  pool:
    vmImage: macos-latest  # Use the latest macOS image available

  steps:
  - checkout: self
    fetchDepth: 1  # Fetch only the latest commit for faster checkout

  # Node.js setup to use the specified version
  - task: NodeTool@0
    displayName: 'Setup Node.js'
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '18.x'  # Use Node.js version 18.x

  # Install dependencies using Yarn
  - task: Yarn@3
    displayName: 'Install dependencies'
    inputs:
      verbose: false

  # Clean Xcode derived data to ensure a clean build environment
  - task: Bash@3
    displayName: 'Clean Derived Data'
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*

  # Install CocoaPods dependencies
  - task: CocoaPods@0
    displayName: 'Install CocoaPods'
    inputs:
      forceRepoUpdate: true
      cwd: ios  # Execute in the ios directory

  # Perform a clean build to remove any previous build artifacts
  - script: |
      xcodebuild clean -workspace ios/raurauAdmin.xcworkspace -scheme raurauAdmin -configuration Release
    displayName: 'Clean Build with Xcode'

  # Build the iOS application
  - task: Xcode@5
    displayName: 'Build iOS IPA'
    inputs:
      configuration: Release
      sdk: iphoneos
      xcWorkspacePath: 'ios/raurauAdmin.xcworkspace'
      scheme: 'raurauAdmin'
      useXcpretty: true
      packageApp: true

# Note: Additional steps for archiving, exporting the IPA, or deploying the build to a service like TestFlight or App Store can be added here.


LLVM has removed the definition of std::char_traits<T> which is not defined in the C++ standard since LLVM 18. As a workaround, you can use std::vector<std::byte>. See the details from this issue.
From LLVM17:

The base template for std::char_traits has been marked as deprecated and will be removed in LLVM 18. If you are using std::char_traits with types other than char, wchar_t, char8_t, char16_t, char32_t or a custom character type for which you specialized std::char_traits, your code will stop working when we remove the base template. The Standard does not mandate that a base template is provided, and such a base template is bound to be incorrect for some types, which could currently cause unexpected behavior while going undetected.


Am unable to build the ios react native application in Azure DevOps every time i got new error at xcode build phase can this is due to the version capability issues?

I'm not sure, maybe this is a factor, but it still depends on your specific error. Azure DevOps is a platform used for CI-CD. I would suggest that you could build your project successfully on your local machine firstly, then build it using Azure pipeline and use the same version Xcode, etc. This way you can eliminate the impact of Azure DevOps images, agents, etc. And focus on your project.

Yes locally its working fine build happened successfully. Am using xcode 15 for coding and the Azure DevOps not support the xcode 15 can this is the main root cause?

According to your YAML, you are using macos-latest, which is macos-14. In this image, the default Xcode version is 15.4.  But according to the release note of Xcode15, The base template for std::char_traits has been marked as deprecated and will be removed in the next release.  It seems to be the root cause of the issue.

You can try to use the same version Xcode in Azure pipeline as your local machine. For example, using Xcode 15.0.1. Add two lines to your Xcode task xcodeVersion: 'specifyPath' and xcodeDeveloperDir: '/Applications/Xcode_15.0.1.app/Contents/Developer'. See the supported Xcode here.

now facing this issue
/Users/runner/work/1/s/ios/Pods/boost/boost/container_hash/hash.hpp:131:33: no template named 'unary_function' in namespace 'std'; did you mean '__unary_function'?
    struct hash_base : std::unary_function<T, std::size_t> {};

adding these lines in yaml with macos-latest
xcodeVersion: specifyPath
xcodeDeveloperDir: '/Applications/Xcode_15.0.1.app/Contents/Developer'

Can you set up a self-hosted agent on your local machine and run your pipeline using it. Then the pipeline will have the same environment as your local build. If it works, we need to investigate further what's the difference between macos-14 and your local machine.  If it doesn't work, please let me know how you build your project locally? What's the specific version of Xcode? Run xcodebuild -version. What's the result if you build it locally in command line?

xcode version is 15.0.1 and macos version is 14.1.1

when using self hosted agent
LoadError - dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi_c.bundle, 0x0009): tried: '/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi_c.bundle' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi_c.bundle' (no such file), '/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi_c.bundle' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')) - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi_c.bundle

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
